# What are TRW or TRE formatted locations?

Tags: united-states, format, township-range-section

I have data from a U.S. state and for each item, there is a Location ID in the format T##R##E-## Sometimes the E is a W.

What is this format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TRW is township, range and section number format.

You should be able to find a layer\shapefile\etc for states online by looking for TownshipSection, Township, Range & Section, etc..

In my instance, the Washington State Department of Transportation published a layer on arcgis.com.

I spent an hour figuring that out. I hope my answer helps the next person.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably the "LEGAL DESC. NAME' from their https://data.wsdot.wa.gov/arcgis/rest/services/Shared/TownshipSection/MapServer map service (also published by WSDOT)

```
{ "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features":[
{
   "type":"Feature",
   "id":0,
   "bbox":[-120.259386, 47.174138, -120.131579, 47.26231],
   "geometry":
   {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[ [-120.259386, 47.26183], [-120.25024, 47.261956], [-120.248768, 47.261982], [-120.239658, 47.262139], [-120.237732, 47.262143], [-120.229077, 47.26216], [-120.227133, 47.262184], [-120.218406, 47.262293], [-120.216536, 47.262292], [-120.207646, 47.262287], [-120.205886, 47.262286], [-120.196993, 47.262281], [-120.195236, 47.262282], [-120.191792, 47.26231], [-120.186777, 47.262282], [-120.17656, 47.262283], [-120.174577, 47.262277], [-120.154861, 47.262235], [-120.152879, 47.262237], [-120.133074, 47.261969], [-120.131579, 47.26188], [-120.131796, 47.245668], [-120.131813, 47.231497], [-120.13186, 47.217111], [-120.131905, 47.20289], [-120.131956, 47.188406], [-120.132194, 47.174138], [-120.153336, 47.174692], [-120.174554, 47.174771], [-120.195793, 47.174697], [-120.217035, 47.174878], [-120.238243, 47.175242], [-120.25929, 47.17556], [-120.259106, 47.190114], [-120.258975, 47.204859], [-120.258339, 47.219388], [-120.258402, 47.226367], [-120.258469, 47.233344], [-120.258536, 47.240322], [-120.258621, 47.243903], [-120.258708, 47.247655], [-120.259052, 47.25485], [-120.259386, 47.26183]]] },
   "properties":{
      "LDID":"71433",
      "LEGAL DESC. NAME":"T20-0N R21-0E",
      "OBJECTID":"1086",
      "PLSMER":"33",
      "RANGE":"21",
      "RANGE DIRECTION":"E",
      "SHAPE.STArea()":"1004982735.629028",
      "SHAPE.STLength()":"126830.559894",
      "Shape":"Polygon",
      "TOWNSHIP":"20",
      "TOWNSHIP DIRECTION":"N"
   }
}
]}
```

Comment: Could have been, and they are used for that, but in my case the items in the data were not property lots (polygons). They would have been more properly provided as Points. But it is very much related to this topic and I think your answer will help others as well who end up here.